# Showing percentage related to a fixed data using Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a value from the database that define the value max 100% of my serie.

But, I wanna only show data from one serie and using this value from database to set my 100%.

For example, I have this serie:

```
  $(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    });
});
```

But my max value from data base is 250. How I can set it and show this in percentage.

Comment: do you looking for this [http://jsfiddle.net/Evsw4/71/](http://jsfiddle.net/Evsw4/71/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use percent parameter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.stacking